# Uniform Convergence of sequence of measurable functions

Tags: measure-theory

I'm trying to work through problems in Royden Fitzpatrick and I'm stuck on the following problem:

Suppose $\{f_n\}$ converges to the real-valued $f$ pointwise on E, where each  $f_n$ is measurable on E. Show the $E=\bigcup_{i=1}^nE_i$, where $E_i$ is measurable, and $\{f_n\}$ converges uniformly to $f$ on each $E_i$ for $i>1$, and $m(E_1)=0$.

I've considered using Littlewood's Three Principles or Egoroff's Theorem, but I really am stuck as to how to approach this problem. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Egoroff's theorem, we have $E_i$ such that $\{f_n\}$ converges uniformly to $f$ on $E_i$ and $m(E\setminus E_i)<1/i$. Now let $E_1 = E\setminus \bigcup_{i=2}^\infty E_i$ and note that
$$m(E_1) = m\left(E\setminus \bigcup_{i=2}^\infty E_i\right)\le \inf m(E\setminus E_i)=0.$$

Comment: Is there an assumption somewhere that $E$ has finite measure? Because Egoroff's theorem applies only when the domain has finite measure

Comment: I think you failed to consider $E$ possibly having infinite measure, though the proof is easily fixed by intersecting $E$ with $[-i, i]$ for each $i$